# PHP Redirect Back To Where User Was

Tags: php

Suppose I have this script :

http://www.example.com/profile.php?uid=12345

And inside this script, there's a send message feature which is handled by sendmessage.php. What sendmessage.php actually does is to INSERT something into the database then redirect back to where user started (profile.php?uid=12345).

I tried to use header("Location: profile.php").

But since profile.php requires ?uid=12345 in the URL [and it's dynamic], my redirect plan is not working.

How do I 'pass' the current URL.  In my case 'profile.php?uid=12345' to sendmessage.php using the GET method.  And then, once sendmessage.php has completed processing, send the user back to their own screen (profile.php?uid=12345)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `profile.php?uid=12345` if you are using form to send data to `sendmessage.php`
then you can have a hidden field like -

`<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">`

Then in `sendmessage.php` you can use `header("Location: ".$_REQUEST['redirect_to']);`'

Comment: unfortunately, in my case, I'm not using FORM to submit data. so Input tag won't apply. but I agree with your solution by using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], just still figuring how to pass this without Inout tag. any help?

Comment: I think when you are not using input tag then you can make redirect_to kind of url parameter and give it the value of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] after encoding and suitably decode it where needed

Comment: .... like sendmessage.php?redirect_to=urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) and inside sendmessage.ph you can do urldecode($_GET["redirect_to"]) ..... some test may be needed because I used something like this a long time back

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Note from PHP.net:

`The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.`

Comment: i think i remember reading that referer value doesn't always populate, is that the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case, but it is the only server-side way to get the URL, without passing the previous URL into a $_POST or $_GET variable.

Comment: it says : Not all user agents will set this. well, what doesn't? IE, Safari or..?

Comment: All established browsers (that is, all desktop browsers and most mobile browsers) will set it. The wording is only there to say it's a client-side thing and that - as with a lot of stuff in web programming - you don't have any guarantees it is set. It is perfectly suitable for your needs.

Comment: @RobertHanson Look at this article, especially the `Referer Hiding` section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer In all honesty, I really recommend passing this the redirect back URL as a $_POST or $_GET parameter for PHP to redirect back to. HTML5 offers an option to not include this header in the send request, which will prevent PHP from accessing this info.

Comment: If you go with the variable, please consider the phishing attacks though; http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks

Comment: @cwap Good reminder! Just remember that this question was tagged as PHP. ;)

Comment: Ya, was lazy, and that was the first article that popped up on google :)

Answer (score 0):

one trick is to populate the information in the link itself, so that way when you go to a different page, those params will still be there... if you so desire, you can use a param as a previous url.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make sure that you send the uid as part of the form submission data.

Then you can reconstruct the URL using the passed in value:

header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . $_GET["uid"]);

Or, store the user ID in their session.  That way it is always available in $_SESSION["uid"] and you won't have to remember to make an otherwise extraneous field in your forms.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the variable to the sendmessage.php like

```
sendmessage.php?uid=<?php echo (isset($_GET['uid']) ? (INT)$_GET['uid'] : 'default') ?>
```

Then on the sendmessage.php.  Use something like

```
header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . (isset($_GET['uid']) ? (INT)$_GET['uid'] : 'default') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GET and some javascript. Using this method avoids the issues with using PHP's header function.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.location = \"profile.php?uid=" . $_GET["uid"] .    "\"</script>";
```

Make you sure check that the "uid" is actually passed. You could also store the uid in a session variable when the user first logs on, and then use that in my example thus avoiding having to use GET. Either way works.